# avoid unwanted comment line into files in git merge/rebase

Tags: git

how to avoid this comment line into the files while git merge/rebase through terminal

comment line : <<<<<<< HEAD
comment line : >>>>>>> student

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
6th change // from master
=======
5th change // student branch
>>>>>>> student
```

Comment: You can't, that's a conflict that needs to be resolved manually.

Comment: oh if i am working with 100+ files, if this happened how i can manually check all the files

Comment: Yes. In that case you might want to use some shell commands to strip out what you don't want. Whenever you see comments like that, it means git can't decide for you anymore, it needs your help.

Comment: `git status` will show you which files you need to merge under "Unmerged paths".

Comment: Maybe you can use a [merge strategy](http://git-scm.com/docs/merge-strategies) to prevent such conflicts.

Comment: Also, to quickly find conflicting files in a quite long `git status` output without being forced to scroll up and potentially miss some files, use `git diff --staged --name-only --diff-filter=U`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of avoiding them, you could properly resolve the merge conflict using an appropriate merge tool.

Refer to

- The official [git merge tool page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool)
- or [this blog post](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/merging-with-a-gui/) for a use case example